# Select a tag with a unicode char in its id

Tags: jquery, sizzle

In HTML 5, unicode characters are allowed in a tag's `id` attribute.  And the Sizzle library used by jQuery claims to have full unicode support.

My HTML file includes:

```
<p id='§'>Hello</p>
```

and doing this returns an empty array:

```
$('§')
```

Why doesn't this work?

(using jQuery 2.2.3)

Comment: as its id...change it to $('#§')..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the element by its CSS id syntax:

```
$('#§')
```

Adding the '#' before the identifier name should make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Change $('§') to `$('#§')`..as we can access any element with its id usinng #